# How Iterate each element row and compare with another elements in row

Tags: python, opencsv, sift

I have to fetch the values from CSV within my local machine and iterate each element and compare them with each element of another row.

[image: Comparison image]

My CSV is stored in my Local C drive and read the value, now I need help to iterate each element from source and target.

```
import csv
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test_readwrite.csv') as cs:
csv_reader = csv.reader(cs)
#displaying it line by line
for line in csv_reader:
    print(line)
#closing the connection
cs.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this could be marked as a duplicate.
Nevertheless, using pandas should make it easier to compare.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Compare column 1 and column 2
def compare(x, y):
    # Your condition, return true or false
    # I am using equality
    return x == y

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: compare(x['col1'], x['col2']), axis=1)
```

This should about fulfil your requirement